# Sard's theorem on tangent bundle

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and $h \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be twice continuously differentiable maps with $n > m$, where $0$ is a regular value of $h$. By Sard's theorem, we see that the set of critical values of $\nabla f$ (continuously differentiable) is negligible.

Consider now the $\mathcal C^2$-manifold,
$$
    M = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n, ~h(x)=0\}.
$$
We can consider the twice continuously differentiable restriction $f_{|M} \colon M \to \mathbb{R}$. We could then say that,
$$
\nabla f_{|M} \colon M \to TM,
$$
is continuously differentiable and proceed to apply Sard's theorem. But the map I am really interested in is not exactly $\nabla f_{|M}$ or at least not written as such, specifically I would like to only "select" the value of $\nabla f_{|M}$, and discard the point at which it applies. Any idea what I am missing here?

I think I could cover the manifold with a countable atlas, and using each chart to locally look at $f_{|M}$ as an application from $\mathbb{R}^{n-m} $ to $\mathbb{R}$, I can apply Sard's theorem as before. This tells me that for each open of my atlas, the set of critical values is negligible, then since there are only countably many negligible sets, the set of critical values is negligible.

How does that sound like?

Comment: Do you mean for $h:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, with $0$ a regular value?

Comment: I also don't understand what you mean by wanting only to select the value of $\nabla f_{|M}$ and discard the point to which it applies. Can you explain more what it is you want?

Comment: If I understand what you are doing correctly, doesn't your notion of "criticality" (using the local charts) depend on the coordinates? I feel like you probably want to introduce a connection to make sense of this.

Comment: I think you are right. I'm just not knowledged enough yet! From what I see that could do. But basically, I was trying to show that the following property is generic: the Hessian of $f$ at point $x$, restricted to $(T_xM)^2$, is non-singular for all $x \in M$.

Comment: You can at least write it as a vanilla statement that $P(x)H(x)P(x)$, where $P(x)$ is the projection on the null-space of the Jacobian (which is $T_xM$) and $H(x)$ is the Hessian of $f$, has rank $n-m$. And that does not depend on the coordinates? Or you mean the tangent space (thus $P(x)$) depends on the coordinate?

Comment: The Hessian of $f$ depends on the coordinates, no? (Rather, the connection between the Hessian of $f$ and the differential of this thing you call $\nabla f$)

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to add that the Hessian is non-singular _at points where the gradient vanishes_! Like in the unconstrained case, Sard's theorem gives a good motivation as to why it is generic that the Hessian is nonsingular when the gradient vanishes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104076/discussion-between-olivier-massicot-and-willie-wong).